# Minimal surfaces for planar octagons and nonagons

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry

**4**, 6, 8 triangles can make a tetrahedron and up.
**6**, 8, [9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_graph), 10 quadrilaterals can make a cube and up.
**12**, 16, 18, 20 pentagons can make a [tetartoid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheTetartoid/) or dodecahedron [and up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609854/).
**7**, 8, 9, 10 hexagons can make make a [Szilassi toroid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheParametrizedSzilassiPolyhedron/) [and up](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/ToroidalRegularHexagonal.html).
**12**, 24 heptagons can make a [heptagonal dodecahedron](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/HigherGenus.html) or [Klein quartic 3-torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinQuartic.html) (shown below).

[image: klein quartic]

4, 6, 12, 7, 12, ... what is next in this sequence?

Could it possibly be 15, with Foster graph F040, which I call the Moving Day graph after Loyd's Moving Day puzzle?  If so, how can those octagons be made planar to contain a 3d-printable space?  Or is it some other graph?  Perhaps 24 octagons can be linked together in a way similar to the [24-cell](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/24-Cell.html)?

[image: Moving Day Graph]

For nonagons, is it Foster F060A, or the [Biggs-Smith graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Biggs-SmithGraph.html)?

Anything between 12 and 24 for heptagons?

Comment: A [144 octagon solution](https://www.quora.com/Does-a-polyhedron-exist-in-which-all-faces-are-octagons) by Andrew Weimholt exists.  It likely isn't minimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I have an answer to one of your many sub-questions, and here it goes:

**No, the minimum for octagons is neither 15 nor 24.**

[image: Minimal octagons]

This guy has 12. Each face is one of the following shapes:

[image: faces]

The geometric symmetry is relatively low ($\bar4$ in Hermann–Mauguin notation).

The construction details are below:

Take this one (left), overlap is with a tetrahedron (right):

[image: construction-1]

I mean, like this:

[image: construction-2]

Then subtract the tetrahedron from the other one.

[image: construction-3]

Comment: Wow.  That's quite amazing.

Comment: Awesome! Could you share the code for generating the faces of this surface?

Comment: @shamisen What code? It's a file in GeoGebra. Then again, Ed did actually publish some code: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1520664?fbclid=IwAR2FjNX7Opkn2fQ8rzPF-xkUgzfdo5OOZR27IaFG5bX_uTeLCWlt-rNNdaM

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks :)

Comment: A friend of mine produced a better rendering: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0YySTDN-xwyfE6kGHamkx3Nbu4OaSrO/view

Comment: Interactive online model is now available: http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/OverarchingOctagonalDodecahedron.html

Answer (score 2):

Going against the customs of this site and my own habits, I decided to add another answer to the same question, because I can't think of a better place where to put this. Strictly speaking, it is an answer to a different question, which the OP did not ask, but probably had in mind.

Behold the figure made of twelve 11-gons.
[image: Undecagons figure]

Pity it has many pairs of faces share more than one edge, and consequently many pairs of faces not sharing an edge, and hence is **not** the much sought-after hypothetical continuation to the series of polyhedra in which every face meets every other (tetrahedron $\to$ Szilassi $\to\;???$).

Each face is one of the following shapes:

[image: faces]

The geometric symmetry, believe it or not, is again $\bar4$.

The construction details are below:

First we take a prism made out of a concave quadrilateral.
[image: beam]

Then we add another such beam in a criss-cross fashion, so that their sharp edges cut into each other a bit.

[image: two beams]

And finally we cut a hole of this shape in a tetrahedron.

[image: still view]

Topologically this is a sphere with six handles, just as it should be.

Comment: Interactive online model is now available: http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/OverarchingHendecagonalDodecahedron.html